# Twilio TaskRouter - ordering workers

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I am trying to configure TaskRouter - Ordering Workers as explained in https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/taskrouter/ordering-workers.

However I couldn't find the order_by expression in WorkFlow or Task or TaskQueues from Twilio TaskRouter UI.

Where exactly do I need to configure order_by expression.

Thanks.

Comment: I've just updated the answer, but in case you didn't see, you can now update this through the Twilio console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I'm afraid that the Task Router console hasn't caught up with those features just yet. The best way to add an `order_by` expression to your workflow would be by [updating the JSON config through the API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/taskrouter/workflows) right now.

There is a ticket open to add this to the console though.

**Update**

Setting `order_by` expressions is now possible through the [Twilio TaskRouter UI](http://twilio.com/console/taskrouter/).

Comment: I cannot find where in the console I can use order_by

Comment: @Petran go to edit a workflow, add a filter and you should see ["ordering" as an option, as you can see in this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZM6F.png).

Comment: @philnash 
can you help me with this question. https://stackoverflow.com/q/77445783/3860125